Azure Function not triggered by Service Bus Queue
Perhaps I'm missing something very basic here. Coming from GCP and AWS, Azure Functions are somewhat ... different in some aspects.
What
What I'm trying to do is have an Azure Function triggered by a Service Bus Queue. Or, one step back, I'm publishing to an Event Grid subject and need a function to reliably handle all messages published to that subject. So my thought was to put a queue as inbox in between because I assume that a message is gone if I trigger the function via AEG directly but the function fails to handle it (?).
I don't want to manage connection strings if I don't have to. So I tried identity-based auth, as well as Service Connector. But with neither of them does my function get triggered by messages in the queue.
How
I'll strip the probably unrelevant parts of the infra.
# topic
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_topic" "this" {
  name                = "mytopic"
  input_schema        = "CloudEventSchemaV1_0"
  # ...
}

# service bus namespace ...

# queue
resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "this" {
  name                                 = "myqueue"
  namespace_id                         = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.xyz.id
  dead_lettering_on_message_expiration = true
  enable_partitioning                  = false
  # ...
}

# azurerm_service_plan Linux Y1

# function app
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "this" {
  name                 = "myfunctionapp"
  # ...
  storage_account_access_key    = azurerm_storage_account.xyz.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id               = azurerm_service_plan.this.id
  public_network_access_enabled = true
  builtin_logging_enabled       = true
  https_only                    = false
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.11"
    }
    always_on                              = false
    app_scale_limit                        = 20
    pre_warmed_instance_count              = 0
    cors {
      allowed_origins = ["https://portal.azure.com"]
    }
  }
  app_settings = {
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags"                      = "EnableWorkerIndexing"
    # what I tried first
    "AZURE_SERVICEBUS_FULLYQUALIFIEDNAMESPACE"      = "${azurerm_servicebus_namespace.this.name}.servicebus.windows.net"
    # identity-based
    "ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace" = "${azurerm_servicebus_namespace.this.name}.servicebus.windows.net"
    "AZURE_STORAGEBLOB_RESOURCEENDPOINT"            = # ...
  }
  sticky_settings {
    # don't actually know what these are yet
    app_setting_names = [
      "AZURE_STORAGEBLOB_RESOURCEENDPOINT",
      "AZURE_SERVICEBUS_FULLYQUALIFIEDNAMESPACE",
    ]
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      app_settings["WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"]
    ]
  }
}

# deploying azurerm_function_app_function via tf actually just does not work, I'm deploying via VSC

# subscription
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "this" {
  name                                 = "mysub"
  scope                                = azurerm_eventgrid_topic.this.id
  event_delivery_schema                = "CloudEventSchemaV1_0"
  advanced_filtering_on_arrays_enabled = false
  service_bus_queue_endpoint_id = azurerm_servicebus_queue.this.id
  retry_policy {
    event_time_to_live    = 1440
    max_delivery_attempts = 30
  }
}

# what I tried first but didn't work: service connector
resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "this" {
  name               = "myserviceconn"
  app_service_id     = azurerm_linux_function_app.this.id
  target_resource_id = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.this.id
  client_type        = "python"
  authentication {
    type = "systemAssignedIdentity"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "queue_service_bus_data_receiver" {
  scope                = azurerm_servicebus_queue.this.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Service Bus Data Receiver"
  principal_id         = azurerm_linux_function_app.this.identity[0].principal_id
  principal_type       = "ServicePrincipal"
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "queue_service_bus_data_owner" {
  scope                = azurerm_servicebus_queue.this.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Service Bus Data Owner"
  principal_id         = azurerm_linux_function_app.this.identity[0].principal_id
  principal_type       = "ServicePrincipal"
}
# why both roles you wonder? Because I thought it may help: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8261

Function deyployed via VSC:
@app.function_name(name="myfunc")
@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(
    arg_name="msg",
    queue_name="myqueue",
    connection="ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace",
)
def test_function(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    # whatever, just logging to see if it gets invoked
    pass

host.json - I actually have no idea which options apply and what exactly they do yet. I also don't get what "Functions 2.x" and "Extension 5.x" are
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 10,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 4,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
      },
      "sessionHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
        "maxConcurrentSessions": 4
      },
      "batchOptions": {
        "maxMessageCount": 10,
        "operationTimeout": "00:01:00",
        "autoComplete": true
      }
    }
  }
}

When I publish a message to the AEG subject it ends up in the queue but the function never gets invoked.
How do I make this work? I read about Consumption plan maybe not supporting Service Bus Queues (yet)? Does Azure maybe not abstract away scaling to zero and thus just never polls the queue? Do I really have to like add an HTTP trigger and a timer to have this thing actually running? Is my whole setup crap?
Side question - what's the difference between service connector and just identity-based access via role assignments (either user- or system-managed)?
/edit: I see that the topic subscription itself has deadlettering and retires. So I will probably go with this instead.

You are passing everything correctly. What is the exact error message you are getting here. @m02ph3u5

@Jahnavi none. The messages just sit in the queue and the function doesn't get triggered.

Ok. will check and update you. @m02ph3u5

Do you see messages in the myqueue queue?

Yes, messages pile up in the queue.
